# Why my page doesn't display correctly in every browser?

Tags: html, cross-browser

I'm having a problem with a page. Basically what happens is that the code below  in firefox it doesn't display the images, in Chrome it shows the images, but sometimes it doesn't show anything.

The code below should display like an image of a product and below of it, show the name of the product, for example with this:

```
<div class="bloque_prod">
<a class="texto_bloque_prod" href="<? echo (ROOT.'/respiratoria"')?>"><img style="display: block !important; margin: auto;" src="mw\imagen\productos\categorias\respiratoria.gif" /></a> 
<div class="texto_bloque_prod"><a class="texto_bloque_prod" href="<? echo (ROOT.'/respiratoria"')?>">Protecci&oacute;n Respiratoria</a></div>
</div>
```

It should show the "respiratoria.gif" and below it show the text "Protección Respiratoria". And all the products in the code below show be display like in a table.

```
<div class="cont_menu_izq">
    <!-- <a name="Safety" id="ramas" style="color:#D82C17;">Safety:</a> -->
            <div class="mini_space"></div>
            <!-- LINEA 1 -->
            <div class="linea_prod">

                <!-- Producto -->
                    <div class="bloque_prod">
                            <a class="texto_bloque_prod" href="http://www.elexsa.com/P/respiratoria""><img style="display: block !important; margin: auto;" src="mw\imagen\productos\categorias\respiratoria.gif" /></a> 
                            <div class="texto_bloque_prod"><a class="texto_bloque_prod" href="http://www.elexsa.com/P/respiratoria"">Protecci&oacute;n Respiratoria</a></div>
                    </div>  
                <!--Fin producto-->
                <div class="espacio_bloque_prod"></div>
                <!--Producto-->
                    <div class="bloque_prod">

                        <a class="texto_bloque_prod" href="http://www.elexsa.com/P/caidas""><img style="display: block; margin: auto;" src="mw\imagen\productos\categorias\caidas.gif" /></a>
                        <div class="texto_bloque_prod"><a class="texto_bloque_prod" href="http://www.elexsa.com/P/caidas"">Protecci&oacute;n Contra Ca&iacute;das</a></div>
                    </div> 
                <!--Fin producto-->
                <div class="espacio_bloque_prod"></div>
                <!--Producto-->
                    <div class="bloque_prod">
                        <a class="texto_bloque_prod" href="http://www.elexsa.com/P/guantes""><img style="display: block; margin: auto;" src="mw\imagen\productos\categorias\guantes.gif" /></a>

                        <div class="texto_bloque_prod"><a class="texto_bloque_prod" href="http://www.elexsa.com/P/guantes"">Protecci&oacute;n para Manos</a></div>
                    </div>  
                <!--Fin producto-->
                <div class="espacio_bloque_prod"></div>
                <!--Producto-->
                    <div class="bloque_prod">
                        <a class="texto_bloque_prod" href="http://www.elexsa.com/P/visual""><img style="display: block; margin: auto;" src="mw\imagen\productos\categorias\visual.gif" /></a>
                        <div class="texto_bloque_prod"><a class="texto_bloque_prod" href="http://www.elexsa.com/P/visual"">Protecci&oacute;n Visual</a></div>

                    </div>  
                <!--Fin producto-->
</div>
```

Comment: We don't know how it should look!  How it looks now! Please explain more and be more specific about how it shows in every browser and how it shoud be shown.

Comment: I added some description, maybe it's more clear now. thanks :D

Comment: Use the W3C validator before coming here. There's a firefox extension as well, called html validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your src attributes on your image tags have backslashes.  They should be using forward slashes.  Some browsers handle this for you and others don't.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers posted, I see doubled double quotes on some attributes:

```
href="http://www.elexsa.com/P/visual"">
```

http://validator.w3.org/

The W3C Validator service is your friend in cases like this.

Edit: after seeing your PHP code, the aforementioned error is caused by this line:

BAD

```
<a class="texto_bloque_prod" href="<? echo (ROOT.'/respiratoria"')?>">
```

GOOD

```
<a class="texto_bloque_prod" href="<? echo (ROOT.'/respiratoria')?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your slashes backwards on your image `src` properties.  Some browsers have tolerence for this, and others not.  Either way, it's wrong. :)

```
src="mw\imagen\productos\categorias\visual.gif"
```

Should be

```
src="mw/imagen/productos/categorias/visual.gif"
```

...for all of your `src` paths.